# Bootstrap Carousel - Linked Image With Caption

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

This is my first carousel project and I have a question on the proper/preferred way of adding hyperlinks to the images. Here is my item format (using [w3school's example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)):

```
<div class="item"><a href="videos/Reports.mp4" target="_blank">
    <img src="graphics/reportsCarousel.png" /></a>
       <a href="videos/Reports.mp4" target="_blank"><div class="carousel-caption">
          <p>Reports</p>
       </div></a>
  </div>
```

Notice I have both the image and the caption linked, because the caption div caused a dead spot so that only the top and bottom of the image was active, i.e., clickable. I tried putting the caption in the image, but didn't like the results. I also tried moving the caption above and below the image, but the caption didn't display. I really like the way this looks, but wonder if there's a better way to set up the link?

[image: Carousel Example]

Extra Credit: Also, I wonder if there is a way to have two or three images display side-by-side using the current div setup? When I put the second image into the item div the images display vertically instead of horizontally, even using an inline ul. I can do it using a more complicated method, but if I can easily tweak this one it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community. At this point it is unclear to me if you are asking us to do the work for you or if you have a specific issue ("didn't like the results" is not very specific as it is a personal preference)

Comment: So, "...the caption div caused a dead spot so that only the top and bottom of the image was active, i.e., clickable." is not clear enough? Maybe I'm in the wrong forum.

Comment: Are you able to create a [mcve] so that we can troubleshoot the issue? something like a fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net) - you have tried many things that you didn't like it is not clear what you want or why they are not clickable

Answer (score 1):

I had some time today and put this together.  It seems to work.

However, I am not sure it addresses your issues since, lacking a [mcve], I cannot reproduce your issues.

I added the JS to log the click event to console - you may or may not need it in your final version (again I am unsure of what you need since the code you provided is not complete/verifiable)

**Please note**

that the runnable snippet below is inside a frame and the `x-frame-options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN` so the link will not actually work here (you will need to copy/paste into your own page to see the links work)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.item').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked! going to: ' + $(this).find('a').attr('href'));

    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/480/" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>caption 1</h3> 
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/480/" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>caption 2</h3>

        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/480/" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>caption 3</h3>

        </div>
      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/480/" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>caption 4</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt't work. With that code you find the first href ever.
Try this one:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".item" ).each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            console.log('clicked! going to: ' + $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        });
    });
});
```